# Is there a Numpy or Pandas setting to issue a warning whenever a NaN value is created

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I'm spending a lot of time working with Pandas, which uses numpy arrays to store numbers.

In my use-case, there should never be any NaN values - they are indicative that something has gone wrong (usually a Pandas-related screwup such as incorrectly joined dataframes, badly loaded data, etc)

It would be helpful if Pandas or Numpy had a setting that would immediately **issue a warning** if a NaN value appeared in any series in a dataframe. (This question is not about NaN replacement or imputation. Just warnings.)

Yes, one could write lots of local checks at each stage (`do this thing. Now check whether you created NaNs. Do this other thing. Check again whether you created NaNs` etc), but that's horribly verbose and inefficient. What I want to tell pandas is `if you ever put a NaN value in a dataframe, immediately issue a warning` - once, as a global setting at the top of my jupyter notebook.

Does anyone know whether a global setting to do this exists?

Comment: Why do you want to raise a warning when there is a NaN, are you looking for a way to remove the rows containing a NaN or overwrite their content? if yes, check my answer below. If not, please provide more details.

Comment: @MedAli I want to raise a warning when there is a NaN. I will clarify the question.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but can comment on how various other languages do this.  If you have a compiled language (e.g. Fortran or C) you can general control this with compile time flags.  Higher level programs (SAS or Stata) generally handle this like pandas and silently create missing values.  I think the user is going to have to be responsible for checking the results of calculations here.  Accidentally creating NaNs is just one out of thousands of things that can go wrong and the overall approach of modern languages is provide tools for data validation rather than causing run time crashes.

Comment: @JohnE " rather than causing run time crashes. " - I don't want to raise an exception, I just want a nice red warning box to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to raise a warning, you can check if you dataframe contains any `NaN` using `df.isnull().values.any()` tehn you can use the `warnings` module to raise a warning.

Here's a working example:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO 
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> st = """ 
... col1|col2
... 1|
... 2|3 
... """
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st),sep="|") 
>>> df.head() 
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     2     3
>>> import warnings                              ^
>>> if df.isnull().values.any(): 
...     warnings.warn("there is NaN")
... 
__main__:2: UserWarning: there is NaN
>>>
```

If you are looking for a general setting within pandas, based on the source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L213-L5478), The check that the `DataFrame class` does to construct the dataframe doesn't include a way to raise a warning if there is NaN. So, the core pandas has to be updated to add that. Here's an extract of the full check done by the DataFrame class.

```
def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
             copy=False):
    if data is None:
        data = {}
    if dtype is not None:
        dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)

    if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
        data = data._data

    if isinstance(data, BlockManager):
        mgr = self._init_mgr(data, axes=dict(index=index, columns=columns),
                             dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
        import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords
        # masked recarray
        if isinstance(data, mrecords.MaskedRecords):
            mgr = _masked_rec_array_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype,
                                           copy)

        # a masked array
        else:
            mask = ma.getmaskarray(data)
            if mask.any():
                data, fill_value = maybe_upcast(data, copy=True)
                data[mask] = fill_value
            else:
                data = data.copy()
            mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                     copy=copy)

    elif isinstance(data, (np.ndarray, Series, Index)):
        if data.dtype.names:
            data_columns = list(data.dtype.names)
            data = dict((k, data[k]) for k in data_columns)
            if columns is None:
                columns = data_columns
            mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
        elif getattr(data, 'name', None) is not None:
            mgr = self._init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns,
                                  dtype=dtype)
        else:
            mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                     copy=copy)
    elif isinstance(data, (list, types.GeneratorType)):
        if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
            data = list(data)
        if len(data) > 0:
            if is_list_like(data[0]) and getattr(data[0], 'ndim', 1) == 1:
                if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
                    columns = data[0]._fields
                arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
                columns = _ensure_index(columns)

                # set the index
                if index is None:
                    if isinstance(data[0], Series):
                        index = _get_names_from_index(data)
                    elif isinstance(data[0], Categorical):
                        index = _default_index(len(data[0]))
                    else:
                        index = _default_index(len(data))

                mgr = _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns,
                                     dtype=dtype)
            else:
                mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                         copy=copy)
        else:
            mgr = self._init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    elif isinstance(data, collections.Iterator):
        raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
    else:
        try:
            arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
            exc = TypeError('DataFrame constructor called with '
                            'incompatible data and dtype: %s' % e)
            raise_with_traceback(exc)

        if arr.ndim == 0 and index is not None and columns is not None:
            if isinstance(data, compat.string_types) and dtype is None:
                dtype = np.object_
            if dtype is None:
                dtype, data = infer_dtype_from_scalar(data)

            values = np.empty((len(index), len(columns)), dtype=dtype)
            values.fill(data)
            mgr = self._init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                     copy=False)
        else:
            raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

    NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)
```

So, you need to file a feature request to add that to pandas.

Comment: I feel that that's not what Roko Mijic asked for. I think he rather seeks something like the famous `SettingWithCopyWarning`. However, I'm not sure if this is implemented. One could think ouf writing a decorator to perform the checks after an operation and patch the pandas functions one regularly uses. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 the question isn't clear. So I put as much hints as possible and asked for clarifications in the comments.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 exactly. 

I don't want to have to repeatedly tell Pandas to warn me if there are NaNs.

Comment: @MedAli thanks for your answer but as stated in the question I was looking for a way to implement this as a global setting that tells numpy/pandas to check for NaNs in a dataframe after every operation.

Comment: Thanks for editing. 

Maybe someone who knows Pandas extremely well should submit a pull request for this feature.